# Doctrine2 migrations and moveing column to different entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I was trying to read up on Doctrine migrations at http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations/2.0/docs/reference/introduction/en which is not available. Looked in Doctrine Docs and could not find it. Any idea where I can find this information?

Question: What would I do if I needed to "move" column content during migrations? Would I put corresponding php code in the up() function?

Say I have User object, and it has id, name and email in it. But then I decide to create UserData object and move email from User to UseData. How would I go about moving this column and doing migration at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found documentation [here](https://github.com/jwage/migrations).

And yes, I suggest you move your data in the up() method yourself.